# How to set web config - machine config settings?

Tags: c#, web-config, config, machine.config

How to set web config - machine config settings:

```
 <processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="20" minIoThreads="20" /> 

 <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="384" maxConcurrentInstances="2784" maxConcurrentSessions="2400" />
```

What is the meaning of these settings?

```
maxWorkerThreads = ?
maxIoThreads = ?
minWorkerThreads = ?
minIoThreads = ?
maxConcurrentCalls = ?
maxConcurrentInstances = ?
maxConcurrentSessions = ?
```